# How to protect auto-generated sources during clean package in maven?

Tags: java, maven, cxf, xjc

I have a maven config file that triggers autogeneration of `xsd` and `wsdl` classes as follows:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf-xjc-plugin}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-sources</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>

                <configuration>
                    <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                    <xsdOptions>
                        //xsds, wsdls etc
                    </xsdOptions>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

The generated classes go to: `target/generated/src/main/java`.

Problem: running 'mvn clean package' will always remove those classes. How can I prevent it? Is it possible having `clean` remove the full content of the `target` directory apart from the `generated/` one?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? `clean` deletes the `target` directory and everything generated by Maven should go under this directory, so everything is acting like it should. The classes will get re-generated by the next build.

Comment: yes, but - as writte - I want to prevent the regeneration. I have some large any many wsdl files, and regeneration takes a long time. In spite, when eg moving or renaming a package, a `mvn clean` is required to the final `war` package, as otherwise the target might contain als the old compiled classes. Another case would be where a `jar` dependency is upgraded, and old ones should get deleted. In all of these cases not regenerating the wsdl java classes will save several minutes, as they are not necessairy.

Comment: So your real problem is not "how make `maven-clean-plugin` not delete `generated/`" but "how can I avoid regeneration". This is not the same question. This could be done by using a profile for example. Can you update the question accordingly?

Comment: *If* it's impossible to protect a folder during `clean`, then yes, this would be my question.

Comment: And in one fell swoop, [Y turned into X](http://xyproblem.info/). Nice job. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible not to delete some directory using `maven-clean-plugin` but this is definitely not a good idea:

- it goes against Maven conventions
- it forces you to change your POM everytime you want those classes to be generated

### Solution to your exact question (NOT RECOMMENDED)

You can exclude directories with the `maven-clean-plugin` using [`excludeDefaultDirectories`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/clean-mojo.html#excludeDefaultDirectories) and [`filesets`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/clean-mojo.html#filesets) parameters:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
        <filesets>
            <fileset>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>generated/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </fileset>
        </filesets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note that I strongly urge you **NOT** to use this solution.

### Proposed solution

Your actual problem is not to re-generate the classes everytime you build because it takes a lot of time. The goal is then to avoid generation by using a custom profile:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>noGenerate</id>
        <properties>
            <xjc.generate>none</xjc.generate>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>generate</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <xjc.generate>generate-sources</xjc.generate>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

With the following plugin definition:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf-xjc-plugin}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>${xjc.generate}</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                <xsdOptions>
                    //xsds, wsdls etc
                </xsdOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It seems `cxf-xjc-plugin` does not have any `skip` parameter so we have to resort to setting the `phase` to `none` when we want to avoid execution (this is an undocumented feature but it works).

The trick is to define two profiles: one, activated by default, sets a property telling the `cxf-xjc-plugin` to execute in the `generate-soures` phase, while the other one sets a property telling the `cxf-xjc-plugin` not to execute.

As such, when you want to classes to be generated, you can invoke Maven with `mvn clean install` and when you want the classes not to be generated, you can invoke Maven with `mvn clean install -PnoGenerate`.

The real gain and advantage here is that you do not need to change your POM everytime you decide to generate or not the classes.

Comment: Using the `excludeDefaultDirectories`, wouldn't it be possible to use `mvn gnerate-sources` to trigger explicit regeneration?

Comment: @membersound `mvn generate-sources` is always going to execute the `generate-sources` phase so the classes are going to get generated. `clean` is not invoked with `mvn generate-sources`.

Answer (score 2):

I would have another approach.

1st) Configure your xjc plug-in to not erase any files i.e.:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>xjc</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
    <sources>
        <source>  [any xsd] </source>
    </sources>
</configuration>
```

2nd) Use maven-clean-plugin to clean jxc class generated dir in clean stage:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>
<configuration>
    <filesets>
        <fileset>
            <directory>${basedir}/generated/src/main/java/...where the generated classes are</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.java</include>
            </includes>
            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
        </fileset>
    </filesets>
</configuration>
```

This works for me and I hope would be useful.