# NetBeans 12.6, Spring Boot / Maven, Cisco AXL Schema - Background scanning of projects

Tags: spring-boot, netbeans, cxf, maven-3, cisco-axl

Often related to `Background scanning of projects` people complain that this happens when `NetBeans` is started.

I have a `Spring Boot 2.6.x` with `Maven 3.8.2` project, using `Cisco AXL Schema 12.5`.

With `Apache CXF` from this `AXL Schema` a lot of Java source code files are generated.

When I do a `Clean and Build` on my project afterwards immediatly the `Background scanning of projects` starts.

And it takes most of the times recently quite long.

I see for example that it scans also

```
netbeans-12.6/webcommon/jsstubs/corestubs.zip
```

Why should it scan this too when building my project?

But most of the time, although it shows 100% scanning done, it spends in the folder where the generated Java source code files are

```
<project folder>/target/generated/cxf
```

There are 2282 generated Java source code files.

I'm not sure if `NetBeans` hangs or really scans these files, it shows 100% scanning so it should be done.

Often it takes too long so I have to terminate `NetBeans` from the console. After a restart of `NetBeans` the `Background scanning for projects` starts and takes much shorter time, but this is annoying.

What can I do about it?

When I start `NetBeans` from console I do only `./netbeans`. Is there a difference if starting `NetBeans` with `sudo ./netbeans`?

Here is how my project folder/file structure looks like, maybe I don't use correctly:

First of all I extracted the `AXL Schema` next to my `src` folder

```
<project folder>
-> schema
   -> 12.5
      AXLAPI.wsdl
      AXLEnums.xsd
      AXLSoap.xsd
-> src
   -> main/...
   -> test/...
```

In `pom.xml` I use

```
...
<build>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/schema/12.5/AXLAPI.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <wsdlLocation>classpath:schema/12.5/AXLAPI.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                        <extraargs></extraargs>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
...
<resources>
...
    <resource>
        <directory>./</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>schema/**</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>  
    <resource>
        <directory>target/generated/cxf</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.java</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
...
</resources>
</build>
...
```

Maybe this `pom.xml` setup is not correct, and that's why the `Background scanning for projects` works wrongly.

When I look into the resulting `war` file after build, I see

```
WEB-INF
-> classes
   -> com/cisco/axl/api/_12
   -> schema/12.5
```

and there are artifacts which might not belong there.

For example in `com/cisco/axl/api/_12` there are not only the `class` files but all related generated `Java` source code files (all 2282).

And perhap `schema/12.5` shouldn't be in the `war` file too.

Comment: `<resource><directory>target/generated/cxf</directory>` has "flavors"! what are you trying to achieve? (with this...browse the generated sources in project explorer!? ..please try the defaults (cxf-output-folder...)

Comment: `<resource><directory>./</directory>`  also not as designed/not good for netbeans

Comment: NetBeans complained that it couldn't find the generated Java source files, so I solved it with the <resource><directory>target/generated/cxf</directory>...</resource>. After I added this to pom.xml no errors in NetBeans.

Comment: Could you please provide an answer with some code snippet for the pom.xml, I'm not sure how to change it. Firstly the AXL Java source code files have to be generated, for this the <plugin> was specified, and the folder where those are generated is <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>. But when I tried to use one of the generated Java source code files, for example RPhone.java, NetBeans didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this pom:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <wsdlOptions>
                <wsdlOption>
                  <wsdl>src/main/resources/wsdl/CustomerService.wsdl</wsdl>
                </wsdlOption>
              </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

(Latest [cxf-codegen-plugin](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html), no additional config, wsdl file [from here](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/distribution/src/main/release/samples/wsdl_first/src/main/resources/CustomerService.wsdl), java ee dependencies)

Running `mvn clean install` ("Clean and Build Project"...takes less than 5 seconds with this wsdl), and gets us:

[image: nice picture]

..this nice picture (resolution of generated sources! grouped by provider (cxf)...we could have more).

#### Conclusion

Netbeans is mature regarding "generated sources". (As long as they are in `target/generated-sources/<provider>`;).

With "generated projects" (maven/gradle e.g. [openapi-plugin](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/plugins/)) on the other hand, I *experienced (netbeans) issues*...and had to externalize/"source control" the "generated stuff" (/project!).

---

#### Don'ts

- `build>resources>resource>directory>.` This will(try to) package your project root (additionally) to target/classes!! (This may confuse *any* IDE.)
- `...>resource>directory>target`, for similar reasons esp. in Netbeans.

#### Hints

- When we want the schemas & definitons *to reside* in (packaged) class path, we place them within `src/main/resources`. Otherwise: outside.
- We add `<resources/>` to our `<build/>`, only when we decided so/know what we do/don't create "circles" (with existing maven-defaults), notto "trick netbeans"! (this is out-dated;)

---

### Update:

- I updated same project with [this wsdl](https://pubhub.devnetcloud.com/media/axl/docs/java-jax-ws-quickstart/assets/axl-demo.zip) (`axl-demo/schema`).
- It generated 1647 classes.
- Netbeans took a while to scan:

  - I increased memory:
    {nb_home}/etc/netbeans.conf:

    ```conf
    netbeans_default_options="-J-Xmx4g ..."
    ```

    (thx to: [How to assign more memory to Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18992219/592355) , ...)
  - (Restarted netbeans,) drank coffee
- But then (once scan was completed): Still "nice picture", we can import/declare/use the generated classes:

[image: bigger project, no problems screenshot]

---

#### Some Tweaks

..[Yoda](https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/#1) added to the build:

- moved cxf-execution to [profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html):

  ```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>gen</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            ...
  ```

  to activate it (only) with `mvn install -Pgen` (or in netbeans (Project>Properties>Run>) Configuration(drop-down)).
- applied this: [How to protect auto-generated sources during clean package in maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32783735/592355) like:

  ```
  <build>
     <plugins>
       <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.0</version>
         <configuration>
           <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
           <filesets>
             <fileset>
               <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
               <excludes>
                 <exclude>generated-sources/**</exclude>
                 <exclude>classes/com/cisco/**</exclude>
               </excludes>
             </fileset>
           </filesets>
         </configuration>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build>
  ```

  I don't agree with "recommended solution"! For "thousands of" classes that *b/rarely change*, who wants to clean & re-generate them  "hundreds" times/day?

Which accelerates us from (`mvn -Pgen clean install`):

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  44.515 s
```

To "Project>Clean and Build" (`mvn clean install`):

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  4.494 s
```

Comment: Cool!?? Just give me a more complex wsdl! :):)

Comment: I created back then this thread and answer my qestion myself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63297393/spring-boot-project-maven-with-axl-netbeans-cannot-find-generated-axl-packag But didn't recognize at that time the drawbacks. I wil give you a linkt to the WSDL, which is more complex, as soon as possible. I don't build it via command line with mvn.

Comment: You might try this https://pubhub.devnetcloud.com/media/axl/docs/java-jax-ws-quickstart/assets/axl-demo.zip It is up to 8.5, but should suffice. Extract it, copy the 'schema' folder into your Spring Boot with Maven project (might generate one from start.spring.io). You might remove everythiing else within the schema folder but leave just the '8.5' folder), and try to generate the AXL Java source code files, and try to use those within you project, like RLine.java or so.

Comment: found it already! ;) (v8!;)

Comment: ..now my netbeans also stunnning :):) ~1500 classes: it took some time to scan, i could not cancel + had exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240292/discussion-between-xerx593-and-neblaz).

Comment: I tried your Hint, and have an improvement so far in regards that my war file is much cleaner now, no generated AXL Java source code files and no AXL schema folder in there. BUT still I cannot mark your answer as correct, because the main problem here is the Background scanning for project time. The build time (with generating the AXL Java source code files) is about 38 sec, but that is not the problem.

Comment: Also, the maven-clean-plugin (according to the link it is not recommended), prevents generating the AXL Java source code files each time, OK, but stil after the Clean and Build it scans them.

Comment: Maybe for this particular project, with so many generated Java source files it might be a solution, to only once generate the AXL Java source code files, put them into a package in the project structure (for example src/main/java/myprojcect/cisco/...) and comment out the CXF plugin in the pom.xml, so when Clean and Build is done, no generation happens, and no large amount of generated files are scanned.

Comment: yeah..the scanning is a problem... but only 1 time! ...the axl wsdl (version 12) will never ever change! "Not recommended": By Whom for what reasons!? ;) I *recommend* (now) opposite! (for the mentioned reasons)

Comment: clean& build costs me now (with >1k classes): 5 seconds, no scanning takes place after that. netbeans startup: <10 seconds.

Comment: With my "solution": after clean build, netbeans has to scan your (main) classes, but not the generated ones!

Comment: yes, your approach in "the maven way": put it (the wsdl + cxf-plugin) into a separate module/project/pom!(with identifying group:artifact:version...) "check it in", build release deploy...and in your "main project" just: `<dependency>that-lib`